# Ribbon Workbench : "1:Attribute - datafieldname of ControlStep cannot be null or empty"

Tags: ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013, workbench

I tried using RibbonWorkbench for CRM 2013 in order to create a button to convert one of my entity into another (pretty much like the qualify lead button does to build an opportunity).

I created a split button, that divides itself into two sections : evolution and incident. I then created the commands behind the two sections and associated two web ressources (JScript) that i before created using the main CRM interface.

And... Well that's pretty much the only things I've did using RibbonWorkbench. 
But when trying to publish the solution, I'm having an error :

```
Your solution could not be implemented
Reasons :
1:Attribute - datafieldname of ControlStep cannot be null or empty.
```

I've search and can't find what the system calls Attribute nor ControlStep.
I might have search wrong, but i can't seem to find any clue while searching in the Microsoft Dynamics Community or simply internet.

Can anybody guide me to understand this error ?

Edit : As asked here is the UML Code that has been directly generated by RibbonWorkbench.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RibbonDiffXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CustomActions>
    <CustomAction Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Form.cpncyd_ticket.MainTab.Save.Controls._children" Sequence="55">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <SplitButton Alt="$LocLabels:cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.Alt" Command="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo" Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo" Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/ResolveCase_32.png" Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/ResolveCase_16.png" LabelText="$LocLabels:cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.LabelText" Sequence="55" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.ToolTipDescription">
          <Menu Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.Menu">
            <MenuSection Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.toIncident" Title="$LocLabels:cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.toIncident.Title" Sequence="10" DisplayMode="Menu16">
              <Controls Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertToIncident.Controls" />
            </MenuSection>
            <MenuSection Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.toEvolution" Title="$LocLabels:cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.toEvolution.Title" Sequence="20" DisplayMode="Menu16">
              <Controls Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.Section3.Section.Controls" />
            </MenuSection>
          </Menu>
        </SplitButton>
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
  </CustomActions>
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates" />
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions>
    <CommandDefinition Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.Evolution">
      <EnableRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="Evolution" Library="$webresource:cpncyd_ticket.Evolution" />
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
    <CommandDefinition Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.Incident">
      <EnableRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="Incident" Library="$webresource:cpncyd_ticket.Incident" />
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
  </CommandDefinitions>
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
    <DisplayRules />
    <EnableRules />
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels>
    <LocLabel Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.LabelText">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Convertir" languagecode="1036" />
        <Title description="Convert Into" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.ToolTipTitle">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Convertir en tant que" languagecode="1036" />
        <Title description="Convert into" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.ToolTipDescription">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Convertir le ticket en tant que ... " languagecode="1036" />
        <Title description="Convert this ticket As Evolution, Incident or Closed Ticket." languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.ConvertTo.Alt">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Convertir en tant que..." languagecode="1036" />
        <Title description="Convert into..." languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.toIncident.Title">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Incident" languagecode="1036" />
        <Title description="Incident" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="cpncyd.cpncyd_ticket.toEvolution.Title">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Evolution" languagecode="1036" />
        <Title description="Evolution" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
  </LocLabels>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Comment: Will you post your ribbon xml?

Comment: It is done ! Sorry for the delay and many thanks for the demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a message that is to do with the Ribbon Xml - it is coming from a Process I think - try creating a solution that only contains the entity that you are trying to edit and then load that into the RibbonWorkbench.

The Ribbon Workbench will export the solution you load then re-import it, so a import fails due to an error with any component then the publish will fail.